# ndk how to use fanotify to watch /proc/pid/maps?

Tags: android-ndk, fanotify

```
#include "linux/fanotify.h" // can work

#include "sys/fanotify.h" // error
```

The fanotify is a linux kernel.

When I want to init fanotify to watch a file:

`use of undeclared identifier 'fanotify_init'`

It's there a way to use the fanotify lib? What should I do in the `CMakeLists.txt` file?